# Geometry Node - Force UV Unwrap orientation

Tags: uv, node-editor, geometry-nodes, geometry

I'm using UV to project a grid of point on my mesh to create a rooftile.
However, sometimes the UV unwrap node gives me UV that are not oriented properly. They are tilted. The Pack UV Islands rotate option doesn't help much.
How would you treat this issue? Is there a trick to force the orientation of the generated UV? I tried by creating my own UV box mapping node but I lose the nice unwrap feature that really flatten the faces. The result is not as good.

[image]
the two big shapes on the left are correctly oriented, the two small triangles on the right are tilted. In the screenshot I forgot to turn off the Rotate option, the problem still the same

[image]
It gives me this kind of result

The best would be to be able to maintain a consistency in the UV orientation when they are generated before the packing. The shape of the roof and the number of islands won't be the same all the time at the end.

Thanks in advance!

[image]